# Finding League of Legends language files

Tags: league-of-legends

Is it possible to find and edit Lol language files? Like item names and such. I want to try and localize it in my language for my personal use.

I've tried searching it in whole Lol folder but found nothing.

Comment: Maybe not a complete dupe (and not answerable enough), but the answer is talking about a file, and editing lines 667/700, so I assume their are lines left that maybe are item names and such. It´s worth a look

Comment: What language are you trying to localise it to?

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR

I don't think anyone outside of Riot knows what file you're looking for anymore, since this topic doesn't seem to have been addressed for over two seasons. I would make a post on the forums and as a Rioter for assistance.

---

I found the file in my PBE version, but I can't seem to track it down specifically on my Live version. But in the PBE one, yes, you can rename the item names. Other things you can re-text: stat names like armor pen and hp5, abbreviations such as gp10 and cdr, shopkeeper messages, tooltip text, "recommended items" category names, names of structures, spectator control tooltips and MUCH MUCH more. They even have funny things like "Unable to surrender due to the game situation being not all that bad" listed that I never see come up. Good stuff.

But it should be noted that I haven't used or updated PBE since late 2013. This seems to match the timestamps of every other form post I've found so far on this topic. So what i'm thinking is, you can't do it anymore, or they made it more difficult. And believe me I've looked. I tried every folder I could find and went through every txt file in the folder.

So what I feel is most likely is that they updated their system for storing the information and it is now stored in a new format under a different title. So it likely exists and would be easy to modify... if you knew where it was and could read the file. So I would take a trip to the forums and ask for some help from a Rioter.

Comment: To whoever down voted this, it would be wonderful if you could leave a comment to explain how it could be improved.